# How to get the xpath for whole website in java or javascript

Tags: java, javascript, xpath

Hi i want the xpath for when i  give url and i get the elements xpath for whole website.For exmple

I have a html file like

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" " "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
  <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
  <head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
   <title>Untitled Document</title>
   </head>
   <body>
   <h4>Test</h4>
    <input type="text" id="firstname" name="first" value="" />
   </body>
   </html>
```

I need a output like following format

```
/html/body/h4

//*[@id="firstname"]
```

how to done this using javascript or java.

Answer (score 0):

It is certainly possible to generate XPath expressions for elements in a document but such an algorithm would usually implement one approach and if the result for the `h4` element is `/html/body/h4` then the result for the `input` element would be `/html/body/input`. And your posted sample is an XHTML document where elements are in the namespace `http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml` which requires the use of a prefix in the XPath expressions with XPath 1.0. So far your requirements are not well defined.

To give you a sample, see http://home.arcor.de/martin.honnen/javascript/storingSelection1.html for a function `makeXPath` which you could call for all elements in `document.body.getElementsByTagName('*')`. That function might do in a text/html context, it ignores namespaces. And it uses the DOM Level 3 XPath API which is not supported in IE. So take that as an idea on how to approach the problem, not as a complete answer to implement your requirement.